# HttpAuthenticationContext.Request must not be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am developing application using ASP.NEt MVC 5 WEBAPI 2.2 with OWIN + Identity with Autofac,
I am getting error **HttpAuthenticationContext.Request must not be null.** while calling method of API controller.
API controllers constructor get called but method is not.
Below are my files.

**Global.asx**

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        IocConfig.RegisterDependencies();
        LogConfig.RegisterLog4NetConfig();

       // DataBaseConfig.Initialize();
       //var dbContext = new GoSphereDataContext();
       // Database.SetInitializer<GoSphereDataContext>(new GoSphereInitializer(dbContext));

        //var dbContext = new GoSphereDataContext();
        //if (!dbContext.Database.Exists())
        //{
        //    dbContext.Database.Create();
        //}

    }        
}
```

**IocConfig.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Inject Dependencies which are registered here with Container Builder.
/// </summary>
public class IocConfig
{
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        ContainerBuilder containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register all controllers.
        containerBuilder.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);

        // Register all API controllers.
        containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(PackageController).Assembly);

        // Register HttpContextBase.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType(typeof(HttpContextBase));

        // Register Libs.
        containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(PackageLib).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Lib")).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Register other dependencies.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<GoSphereDataContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerDependency();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerDependency();
        containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataRepository<>)).As(typeof(IDataRepository<>)).InstancePerDependency();

        IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();

        // Create the depenedency resolver for Web API.
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Set MVC DI resolver to use our Autofac container
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        GlobalUtil.LifeTimeComponentContext = container;
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Use camel case for JSON data.
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**MeController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
public class MeController : BaseApiController
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET api/Me
    public GetViewModel Get()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
        return new GetViewModel() { Name = user.Name };
    }

    public MeController(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        : base(lifetimeScope)
    {
    }
}
```

while calling domain/api/me it constructor of **controller get method not called** and before calling **its Get method give error**

1. An error has occurred. 
   HttpAuthenticationContext.Request must not be null.

   System.InvalidOperationException
    at
   System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
   task) at
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at
   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
   task) at
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at
   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

Solve the issue.
In BaseApiController i had override Initialize Method and forgot to call `base.Initialize();`
That's it it solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me so much pain.